# Refunding impossible

Tags: eosio.token, permissions

I wanted to refund my eos manually, but unfortunately, I get the following error message:

transaction declares authority '{"actor":"maczaykowski","permission":"active"}', but does not have signatures for it under a provided delay of 0 ms, provided permissions [], provided keys ["EOS5bmjRPgLbTA43qwvi7mtLJVmFJ12fVSJzT7WysKqHfNc8XeCdT","EOS6kG8b5s4gJrbEha79Vib8e5s5wDHFomgoCCoCPd2qEgJZrcVTM"], and a delay max limit of 3888000000 ms

What did I do wrong?
I use a ledger nano s and started years ago with the fairy wallet in cooperation with my ledger.

Regards

Thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

it seems you do not have the keys for the account you are trying to refund.

here you can see the keys for the account:
https://www.bloks.io/account/maczaykowski#keys

and it seems you provided these keys instead (they are different):
"EOS5bmjRPgLbTA43qwvi7mtLJVmFJ12fVSJzT7WysKqHfNc8XeCdT"
"EOS6kG8b5s4gJrbEha79Vib8e5s5wDHFomgoCCoCPd2qEgJZrcVTM"